# How to read performance counter values without special privileges?

Tags: c#, .net, security, performancecounter, code-access-security

My Office add-in needs to be able to read System.Diagnostics performance counters (CPU, memory, etc) and I can't assume that the user is a member of the administrators group or Performance Monitor Users group.  I noticed that there is a PerformanceCounterPermission object.  Does anyone have an example of how I can use this to allow regular users to read the performance counters?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need administrator permissions to read or set the value on a performance monitor, only create them in the first place.